# CMake + Qt = carved in stone Qt definitions (aka. -DQT_...)?

Tags: qt, cmake, built-in, definitions

First, let's look at the excerpt from my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(Qt4 4.8.0 COMPONENTS QtCore QtGui QtOpenGL REQUIRED)
include(${QT_USE_FILE})
add_definitions(${QT_DEFINITIONS})
```

Therefore, by default we get the following definitions in Debug mode:

```
-DQT_DLL -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_DLL -DQT_DEBUG
```

So the first question is: why there are two `-DQT_DLL` definitions?

Now, if I append, for instance, `remove_definitions(-DQT_DEBUG)` - nothing changes. In other words, either `remove_definitions` command is bugged or these definitions are merely carved in stone.

Then I thought like "OK, maybe `remove_definitions` command is really bugged, let's do it another way." And I did `list(REMOVE_ITEM QT_DEFINITIONS -DQT_DEBUG)`. However, it didn't work either.

Therefore, the second question is: are these definitions really built-in and persistent and cannot be changed under any circumstances?

**NOTE:** Despite problems with editing these built-in definitions, it is still possible add custom definitions, for instance:

```
add_definitions(-DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so here we have several things. It boils down to the `CMake` macros and their logic.

Double `-DQT_DLL` comes from `add_definitions(${QT_DEFINITIONS)})`.
It is enough to specify `include(${QT_USE_FILE})`.

`QT_USE_FILE` defines `QT_DEBUG` (or `QT_NO_DEBUG`) based on the current `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`. If for whatever reason you don't want to have `QT_DEBUG` in the `DEBUG` mode (and to work with `QT_USE_FILE`) there might be a way to do that. `CMake` puts these specific definitions in the directory properties:

```
SET_PROPERTY(DIRECTORY APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG QT_DEBUG)
SET_PROPERTY(DIRECTORY APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE QT_NO_DEBUG)
SET_PROPERTY(DIRECTORY APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELWITHDEBINFO QT_NO_DEBUG)
SET_PROPERTY(DIRECTORY APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_MINSIZEREL QT_NO_DEBUG)
IF(NOT CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES AND NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  SET_PROPERTY(DIRECTORY APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS QT_NO_DEBUG)
ENDIF()
```

Now, you could try tweaking these settings...